# Is it idiomatic to use "to hope" in a sentence in which 'could' or 'can' appear?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Which of the below sentences is more idiomatic in the English language, 1) or 2)? Or, both?

1. I hope that we *could* listen to live calls.
2. I  hope that we *can* listen to live calls.

Answer (score 1):

[Could](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/could) is used as the past tense of *can*, as in the following sentences.

> She said that she couldn't come.

> I couldn't hear what they were saying.

> Sorry, I couldn't get any more.

The equivalent of the second sentence, when written in the present is "I cannot hear what they are saying."

That is only one of the uses of *could*, which is also used to show that something is or might be possible, which also what *can* is used for.

> I could do it now, if you like.

When you are using *hope* in the past, *could* is always used. You would not say "I hoped we can still be friends." That doesn't mean *could* is not used for the present; in some case, *could* is preferred to *can*.

> Could I use your phone, please?

Looking at the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* for *hope [pp*] could*, I get the following sentences. (*[pp*]* is a placeholder for any personal pronoun.)

> "I'll admit, I **did hope you could** prove me wrong," she said to Amber.

> But the plan's authors clearly **hope it could** serve as a template for a "grand bargain" later in the year that could erase perhaps $4 trillion from the deficit over the coming decade.

> I **hope I could** have more time to write love poems only, because I feel it, and I want it, and I need it.

> And so I **hope it could** come up Sunday or Monday of next week.

> I would love to do it. I **hope I could** do it.

> I **hope you could** do it in one lifetime. Let me play the devil's advocate on this whole clearance process and ask, what about the role of competitors in opposing the clearance process?

> What could she do? Louise picked up Elizabeth and carried her as she finished her other chores, one-handed, diapering and feeding the others as best she could, **hoping beyond hope she could** quiet the room before Margaret got back to scold her, came back to see her face, tear-streaked and red, to tell her about the dangers of becoming too attached and how that would compromise her nursing abilities.

> Solar researchers, for example, have sought old sunspot records in **the hope they could** isolate peculiar trends in the activity of the Sun.

There are 65 sentences (23 are spoken English) matching that pattern; in some cases the sentence is using the past (*did hope*), and in some cases *hope* is used as noun.

With *hope [pp*] can*, I get 1056 sentences (483 are spoken English), including the following ones.

> But, yeah, I really **hope she can** stick with this because, again, the jive, the hardest dance you can possibly do.

> I **hope you can** help me.

> I just **hope we can** continue to entertain people.

> I **hope it can work** to our advantage this year.

> Sometimes threat appraisals are irrational, based on the athletes' thoughts about worse case scenarios (e.g., "What if my opponent scores?") or a reflection of low confidence (e.g., "I **hope I can** win").

> I only **hope I can** find a cooperative environment (in the future) as I found here.

To make a comparison, with *hoped [pp*] could* I get 192 sentences (21 are spoken English).

Using a *wish* instead of *hope*, I get the following:

- 3027 (870 are spoken English) sentences match *wish [pp*] could*
- 875 (31 are spoken English) sentences match *wished [pp*] could*
- 22 (17 are spoken English) sentences match *wish [pp*] can*

Answer (score 0):

The second one is more common and natural.

Present tense:

> I hope that we can listen to live calls.

*Could* is used for past tense, so statements like these are grammatical:

> I hoped we could listen to live calls
>
> I had hoped that we could listen to live calls.
>
> I was hoping we could listen to live calls

Comment: Law, without more context it is difficult to say that "I hope that we could listen to live calls" is wrong, no?

Comment: @carlo_r I guess that in certain situations it might be right, but I would never formulate it in that particular way. I've changed the answer to indicate that its not absolutely wrong though.